# FIle Descriptor out of range error while reading from arduino

Tags: python-2.7, logging, raspberry-pi3, arduino-uno

I am getting this error again and again while running my code.

```
Exception in thread Thread-213:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyfirmata/util.py", line 47, in run
    self.board.iterate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyfirmata/pyfirmata.py", line 264, in iterate
    byte = self.sp.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 483, in read
    ready, _, _ = select.select([self.fd, self.pipe_abort_read_r], [], [], timeout.time_left())
ValueError: filedescriptor out of range in select()
```

All i am trying to do is calculate power consumption in my project.
I am sharing part of my code as well. my counter was still counting but after
getting this error, my counter stopped.
Can i use it without iterator, or do i need to stop the iterator. This application should run continuously 24x7. 
so there should be no chance of code error. Please help me get over it. please help me if i am wrong, i learned python from internet only.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/pi/abc/MYPythonGUI.py", line 127, in <lambda>
  File "/media/pi/abc/MYPythonGUI.py", line 119, in updateLabel
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'Memory'
```

here's my code

```
import sys
import logging
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import datetime
import time
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.ods',level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(message)s')
PowerAccumulated = [0,0]
Mem=open('Memory','r')
PowerAccumulated[0] = float(Mem.read())
Mem.close()

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def _Power_Calculations(Self):

        Date_labe2 = QtGui.QLabel(((datetime.datetime.today()).strftime("%d/%m/%y  %H:%M")), Self)
        newfont = QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold) 
        Date_labe2.setFont(newfont)
        Date_labe2.setStyleSheet("color: blue")
        Date_labe2.resize(250,120)
        Date_labe2.move(610,400)

        power_label2 = QtGui.QLabel(str(PowerAccumulated[1]), Self)
        newfont = QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold) 
        power_label2.setFont(newfont)
        power_label2.setStyleSheet("color: blue")
        power_label2.resize(270,120)
        power_label2.move(440,75)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, lambda: Self.updateLabel(power_label2,Date_labe2))
        power_label3 = QtGui.QLabel("KW", Self)
        newfont = QtGui.QFont("Times", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold) 
        power_label3.setFont(newfont)
        power_label3.setStyleSheet("color: blue")
        power_label3.resize(270,120)
        power_label3.move(600,75)



        Self.show()
    def updateLabel(Self, power_label2,Date_labe2):
        try:
            board=Arduino('/dev/ttyACM0')
            iterator=util.Iterator(board)
            iterator.start()
            V1=board.get_pin('a:0:i')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            Voltage=100*(V1.read())

            I1=board.get_pin('a:1:i')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            Current=20*float(I1.read())
            if Current < 0.0976 :
                Current = 0.0976

        except:
            Voltage=0.0
            Current=0.0
        Power=round( ((Voltage * Current * 0.98 * 1.732)/1000),3)
        PowerAccumulated[1] =round((Power + PowerAccumulated[0]),3)
        Self.Voltage = Voltage
        Self.Current = Current
        Self.Power = Power
        Self.PowerAccumulated=PowerAccumulated[1]
        logging.info('Valotage:{} - Current:{} - Power:{} - Power Accumulation:{}'.format(Self.Voltage, Self.Current, Self.Power, Self.PowerAccumulated))
        Mem1=open('Memory','w')
        Mem1.write(str(PowerAccumulated[1]))
        Mem1.close()

        PowerAccumulated[0] = PowerAccumulated[1]

        power_label2.setText(str(PowerAccumulated[1]))
        Date_labe2.setText((datetime.datetime.today()).strftime("%d/%m/%y  %H:%M"))
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, lambda: Self.updateLabel(power_label2,Date_labe2))

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```